# getting the same random index for 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, jquery-selectors

I am building a flashcard web app and I am trying to make a random japanese character appear but at the same time also have a english value to the character.

So I have two arrays (one English and one Japanese) and I have, with the help of someone on here managed to get the random Japanese letter to be displayed.

my question is how do I get the same index value for the english array to check an answer against without breaking the rest of my code?

```
 // kana indexes 
var kanaArray = ["あ","い","う","え","お","か","き","く","け","こ","さ","し","す","せ","そ","た","ち","つ",
"て","と","な","に","ぬ","ね","の","は","ひ","ふ","へ","ほ","ま","み","む","め","も","や","ゆ","よ","ら","り","る",
"れ","ろ","わ","を","ん"]

var kanaEng = ["a","i","u","e","o","ka","ki","ku","ke","ko","sa","shi","su","se","so","ta","chi","tsu",
"te","to","na","ni","nu","ne","no","ha","hi","fu","he","ho","ma","mi","mu","me","mo","ya","yu","yo","ra","ri","ru",
"re","ro","wa","wo","n"]

let getRandomKana = () => kanaArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*kanaArray.length-1)];

let getAnswerVal = kanaEng[Math.floor(Math.random()*kanaEng.length-1)];

//logic

var started = false;
var level = 0;
let kanaPassed = [];

// start and switch buttons 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".startBtn").click(function(){
        started = true
        $('.startBtn').css("visibility", 'hidden');
        $('.switchBtn').css("visibility", 'visible');
        $('h3').text(getRandomKana());
        $('h3').css("visibility",'visible');
        console.log(started)
    })
});

$('.switchBtn').click(function(){
    $('h3').text(getRandomKana());
});

// check answer 
$('.submit').click(function(){
    console.log(getAnswerVal);
    if($('#answerBox').val()===getAnswerVal){
        $('card').css('background-color','red');
    }
});
```

Comment: ... store the index somewhere?

Comment: Store the index in a variable :) Or use a more adapted data structure... `{ "あ":"a", "い":"i", "う":"u" }`

Answer (score 1):

You can make sure to get the first array index and use the same index on the second array so that you can get the same translation. some what like this:

```
const kanaArray = ["あ","い","う","え","お","か","き","く","け","こ","さ","し","す","せ","そ","た","ち","つ","て","と","な","に","ぬ","ね","の","は","ひ","ふ","へ","ほ","ま","み","む","め","も","や","ゆ","よ","ら","り","る","れ","ろ","わ","を","ん"];

const kanaEng = ["a","i","u","e","o","ka","ki","ku","ke","ko","sa","shi","su","se","so","ta","chi","tsu","te","to","na","ni","nu","ne","no","ha","hi","fu","he","ho","ma","mi","mu","me","mo","ya","yu","yo","ra","ri","ru","re","ro","wa","wo","n"];

const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*kanaArray.length);
const randomKanaArray = kanaArray[randomIndex];
const randomKanaEng  = kanaEng[randomIndex];
```

Also you can make it more easier if you store it with JSON obj:

```
const KANAS = [{jap: "あ", eng: "a"},...];
const RANDOM_KANAS= KANAS[Math.floor(Math.random()*KANAS.length)];
console.log(RANDOM_KANAS.jap, RANDOM_KANAS.eng);
```

Comment: Hey so what you said helps in a way but it doesnt give me a random value for the english version. This is the issue I am having with just storing the random value in an index it doesnt seem to match up on both.

Comment: hey @Codechunk could you please explain what exactly you are looking for in the above question editing it?